# Amazon S3 .NET SDK Encrypting Objects Larger Than 5GB

Tags: encryption, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've looked around and haven't come across anything .NET specific, so now I'm here asking for help.  I have the need to upload and encrypt (during the upload operation) objects that will be larger than 5GB.  I will also have the need to copy these objects from folder to folder within a bucket.  I can upload and copy no problem, the issue is that the server-side encryption of the object is not occurring as expected.  In both cases, I'm trying to use the CopyPartRequest class to perform the encryption.  My code is below.  After this opertation, the object is there and is the right size, just not encrypted.  Is there something I'm missing?

```
Dim s3Client As IAmazonS3
s3Client = New AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretAccessKeyID, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1)

Dim uploadResponses As New List(Of UploadPartResponse)()
Dim copyResponses As New List(Of CopyPartResponse)()

Dim initiateRequest As New InitiateMultipartUploadRequest() With { _
    .BucketName = bucketName, _
    .Key = destObject _
}

Dim initResponse As InitiateMultipartUploadResponse = s3Client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initiateRequest)

Dim uploadId As [String] = initResponse.UploadId

Dim metadataRequest As New GetObjectMetadataRequest() With { _
    .BucketName = bucketName, _
    .Key = objToCopy _
}

Dim metadataResponse As GetObjectMetadataResponse = s3Client.GetObjectMetadata(metadataRequest)
Dim objectSize As Long = metadataResponse.ContentLength
Dim partSize As Long = 5 * CLng(Math.Pow(2, 20))

Dim bytePosition As Long = 0
Dim i As Integer = 1

While bytePosition < objectSize
    Dim copyRequest As New CopyPartRequest() With { _
        .DestinationBucket = bucketName, _
        .DestinationKey = destObject, _
        .SourceBucket = bucketName, _
        .SourceKey = objToCopy, _
        .UploadId = uploadId, _
        .FirstByte = bytePosition, _
        .LastByte = If(bytePosition + partSize - 1 >= objectSize, objectSize - 1, bytePosition + partSize - 1), _
         .ServerSideEncryptionMethod = Amazon.S3.ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256, _
         .PartNumber = i _
     }

     copyResponses.Add(s3Client.CopyPart(copyRequest))

     bytePosition += partSize

     If (bytePosition * 100) / objectSize >= 99 Then
         bgCopyMoveFile.ReportProgress(99)
     Else
         bgCopyMoveFile.ReportProgress((bytePosition * 100) / objectSize)
     End If

     i += 1
End While
```

By what I've read, specifying the encryption in the copypartrequest should do it, but it's not for me.

The code above is vb.net, but I can do either VB or C#.  If more information is needed, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this, the problem was in initiating the multipart upload request...I have to specify AES256 encryption there, so

```
Dim initiateRequest As New InitiateMultipartUploadRequest() With { _
    .BucketName = bucketName, _
    .Key = destObject _
}
```

turned into

```
Dim initiateRequest As New InitiateMultipartUploadRequest() With { _
    .BucketName = bucketName, _
    .ServerSideEncryptionMethod = Amazon.S3.ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256, _  
    .Key = destObject _
}
```